# C# WinForms - Manually Added Datagridview using Serialized JSON Object doesn't display data

Tags: c#, json, winforms, datagridview

I've reviewed about 100+ post and articles on SO and elsewhere and have yet to figure out why exactly this example below won't show any columns or rows.  There has got to be a simple thing that I'm doing out of order or just plain wrong that is causing this to fail.

Overall, my goal is to be able to manually add a data grid to a form after a drag and drop of a JSON file to a WinForm.  However, the example below is just test code to just get JSON serialized into an object and then see if I can display the data in a data grid.  I'm using C# WinForms in 2015.

So far no luck.  What am I missing?

**SERIALIZED OBJECT**
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

```
[DataContract]
public class Connections
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id", IsRequired = false)]
    public int id;

    [DataMember(Name = "name", IsRequired = false)]
    public string name;
}
```

**FORM**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView datagrid = new DataGridView();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Connections));
        String testData = "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"testSetting\"}";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testData));
        Connections connection = (Connections)js.ReadObject(ms);
        ms.Close();      

        BindingSource binder = new BindingSource();
        binder.DataSource = typeof(Connections);
        binder.Add(connection);
        binder.Add(connection);
        binder.Add(connection);

        DataGridView datagrid = new DataGridView();
        datagrid.DataSource = binder;
        datagrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        datagrid.AutoSize = true;

        this.Controls.Add(datagrid);
    }
```

Comment: The DataSource can only read properties, and your class only has fields.  Your BindingSource confuses me: typeof?  Adding 'connection' three times?

Comment: Got it.  Finally a straight answer.  Added properties and it works.  The extra bindings were an accident.  Although, doing so adds three rows to the grid.